# rm gives 'No such file or directory' for an existing file

Tags: shell

my command:

```
find . -name "myfile.h" | sed 's/.*/\"&\"/' | awk '{print $1}' |  while read filename; do
rm -r $filename
done
```

OutPut

```
rm: "./xxx/myfile.h": No such file or directory
```

but, when I ran "rm ./xxx/myfile.h", it succeeded!

Comment: use `rm -v -r` instead of `rm -r` to understand what is really happenning

Comment: Any reason for unaccepting?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding double quotes to the file name?  That's the reason you are getting the error.  Also, it is better to invoke rm without the -r option in this context.  Just try this:

```
find . -name "myfile.h" | while read filename; do
  rm -- "$filename"
done
```

More simply, you can use the `-delete` option of `find`:

```
find . -name "myfile.h" -delete
```

Comment: Space is no problem when you enclose the file name variable in double quotes.  Use rm -rf with caution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file tree containing `a/b/myfile.h` and `a/c/myfile.h` your `rm` command gets executed *twice* on the same directory  `a/`

You might want to replace `rm -r` by `rm -v -r` to confirm that intuition.

You could replace `rm -r $filename` by `rm -rf "$filename"` to avoid that message (and remove your `sed` ...)

To debug your [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) replace `rm` by `echo rm`. 
Read [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html)